# Javafx start method runs on AppKit thread instead of Javafx thread

Tags: java, macos, javafx, jpackage

I noticed something weird when running a Javafx app that built by jpackage for Mac OS X.

If I run the following code:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication();
        launch(args);
    }
    
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

The output will be this:
"AppKit Thread"

If I comment out `com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication()` then we get the correct output:
"JavafX Application Thread"

This issue is problematic when I get NullPointerException later on when Javafx tries to load css files because it AppKit thread has a null ClassLoader.

I can reproduce the above problem in that least 3 ways:

- Calling `com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication()` as shown above.
- Calling `new JGoogleAnalyticsTracker(config, GoogleAnalyticsVersion.V_4_7_2);` which is a library I use.

Note: The above problem does not exist when I run my app from Intellij. The problem only occurs when I use `jpackage` to build binary code to start the JVM. I'm using Java 14 and Javafx 14.

My questions:

- What is "AppKit" thread and is it normal that Java would ever call from that thread?
- Is the situation described above a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: What happens if at the beginning of your start method you put this line?  
```
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Test.class.getClassLoader()); 
```
There used to be a bug where the JavaFX launch process resulted in losing the thread context class loader, and this was a workaround.  Maybe it can still help in your situation

Comment: Yes I had already used that as a workaround and it works. But I'm worried that not being in a correct thread might cause instability in Javafx.

Comment: When your on the "AppKit" thread what does `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()` return? The result should establish if there's two threads or if some code is just renaming the FX thread.

Comment: `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()` return true. But I think this is more than just some code renaming it. The AppKit thread also has a null ClassLoader.

Comment: The code which changes the name could also be setting the context class-loader to null. In any case, you can place a watchpoint on the `com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.fxUserThread` field and/or place a breakpoint on the `Thread#setName(String)` method then debug your application and inspect the stack trace to see which code is changing things. I believe it should be possible to connect remotely by specifying the appropriate `--java-options` or even `--add-launcher` when invoking `jpackage` (though I haven't tried).

Comment: Note you may want to set a condition for the breakpoint on the `setName` method so it only stops execution if the old name was "JavaFX Application Thread".

Comment: Remote debugging is gonna be a pain but I'm pretty sure nobody is renaming that thread. After all the method that is culprit is `com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication()` which is part of the standard JDK. I doubt Java decided to change the name of one its methods half through execution. Also note that `AppKit` isn't some random thread. It's part of Mac OS X which Java apparently uses sometimes: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/MacOSXPort/Java+vs.+AppKit+Threading+Manifesto

Comment: Well, `isFxApplicationThread()` uses `==` under-the-hood, so if that method is reporting `true` when you're on the "AppKit Thread" then some code is either renaming the FX thread or is replacing the FX thread. I find the first option much more plausible than the second (not even sure if the second option is possible from outside JavaFX).

Comment: I filed a bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8248127